# Facebook Like needs confirmation?

Tags: plugins, facebook

I use a Facebook Like plugin on my WordPress blog, but it is really weird. I need to press a confirm link, even if the user clicked the like button. But most users won't click twice.

Is this something that is caused by the plugin I use or by Facebook?

Comment: What plugin do you use to add the Like buttons? Please give the link to the plugin in the WordPress.org plugin directory, there are many that are called "Facebook Like". (Use `@Jan` when you reply in a comment and I get a notification)

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing your site locally, like with easyphp or others, then it's normal, it'll work fine when you upload everything. If the problem happens online then it's something else. Do you have the plugin's link?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook adds the Confirm link automatically when their systems detect that you might be cheating or otherwise gaming the system in some way.

If you continually like and unlike the site, even in testing, then you can trigger this mode. If a number of users Like your page but then remove the resulting post from their FB walls or mark it as spam, then you can trigger this mode.

There is no way to un-trigger this. They can't even manually untrigger it. It will resolve itself over time as their system detects correct usage.

And their data actually does show that people do click the Confirm link.

Source: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=93201